# Move data to top or bottom w/ Javascript

Tags: javascript

Ok just got assigned to a new project and have never dealt with Javascript before. Right now the data is moved up and down the grid with the code below. I need to add to the case statement a "top" and "bottom" that will the user the move the selected row to either the top of the grid or the bottom. I am trying to google search answers but not having much luck. Any advice on where I could continue my search would be helpful.

Ok new issue. I added some code that I created. It is in the case statement under "top" and "bottom" The code I added allows me to select an item and move it to the very top of the list. But moving it to the bottom and IE tells me that the script is taking to long. ANy Advice?

Never mind I got the code working. Below is the working code.

```
function move(direction) {
try {
    if (CSAdmin.selectedItem.element &&
CSAdmin.selectedItem.ID) {
        var row = CSAdmin.selectedItem.element;
        var node =
    getNode(CSAdmin.selectedItem.type, CSAdmin.selectedItem.ID);
        if (node) {
            var sibling = null;
            var rowSibling = null;
            var parent = node.parentNode;
            var rowParent = row.parentNode;
            switch (direction) {
                case "up":
                    {
                        sibling = node.previousSibling;
                        if (sibling) {
                            parent.removeChild(node);
                            parent.insertBefore(node, sibling);
                        }
                        //Move the table row 
                        rowSibling = row.previousSibling;
                        if (rowSibling) {
                            rowParent.removeChild(row);
                            rowParent.insertBefore(row, rowSibling);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                case "down":
                    {
                        sibling = node.nextSibling;
                        if (sibling) {
                            parent.removeChild(sibling);
                            parent.insertBefore(sibling, node);
                        }
                        //Move the table row if it isn't the insert row
                        rowSibling = row.nextSibling;
                        if (rowSibling && rowSibling.id.indexOf("new", 0) == -1) {
                            rowParent.removeChild(rowSibling);
                            rowParent.insertBefore(rowSibling, row);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                    case "top":
                    {
                        sibling = node.previousSibling;
                        while (sibling) {
                            if (sibling) {
                                parent.removeChild(node);
                                parent.insertBefore(node, sibling);
                                sibling = node.previousSibling;
                            }
                        }
                        //Move the table row 
                        rowSibling = row.previousSibling;
                        while (rowSibling) {
                            if (rowSibling) {
                                rowParent.removeChild(row);
                                rowParent.insertBefore(row, rowSibling);
                                rowSibling = row.previousSibling;
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                case "bottom":
                    {
                        sibling = node.nextSibling;
                        while (sibling) {
                            if (sibling) {
                                parent.removeChild(sibling);
                                parent.insertBefore(sibling, node);
                                sibling = node.nextSibling;
                            }
                        }
                        //Move the table row if it isn't the insert row
                        rowSibling = row.nextSibling;
                        while (rowSibling && rowSibling.id.indexOf("new", 0) == -1) {
                            if (rowSibling && rowSibling.id.indexOf("new", 0) == -1) {
                                rowParent.removeChild(rowSibling);
                                rowParent.insertBefore(rowSibling, row);
                                rowSibling = row.nextSibling;
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (err) {
    throw new Error("Error moving row:" + err.description);
}
```

Comment: I really don't understand your question. Please add an example of what you're trying to achieve/what you already have.

Comment: What I have is a datagrid. If you select a row and hit either Up or Down button you can move a row up or down one row at a time. I want to add a Move To Top and Move To Bottom button that will move that row either to the top of the grid or to the bottom. The code above currently will either move it up or down one row at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable names in your existing code are kind of confusing (you don't even tell us what `node` is), but this is the basic premise for making it work. I used jQuery to shortcut the work in this example, but the logic is sound and is not reliant on jQuery.

http://jsfiddle.net/qukDJ/

```
//move to top
var currentRow = $(this).closest('tr')[0];     
var firstRow = currentRow.parentNode.childNodes[0];
currentRow.parentNode.insertBefore(currentRow, firstRow);
```

Moving to the bottom is basically the same thing except you want lastRow and insertAfter.

```
var lastRow = currentRow.parentNode.childNodes[currentRow.parentNode.childNodes.length - 1];
currentRow.parentNode.insertAfter(currentRow, lastRow);
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion this is not my code. It belongs to a developer no longer here. I am trying to figure it all out myself. From what I can tell node is slimpy the selectedItem type and ID. I am basing this only on this line var node =getNode(CSAdmin.selectedItem.type, CSAdmin.selectedItem.ID);

Comment: This is not the exact right answer but it was the next based thing it allowed me to figure out what the javascript was doing and allowed me to realize how to do it correctly.